# Modelling a pendulum in Haskell using RK4

Tags: haskell, numerical-methods

I am trying to implement the classical RK4 algorithm in Haskell to solve systems of coupled ODEs, taking the simple pendulum as a sample system. Unfortunately I haven’t been able to fix the following error.

```
Pendulum.hs:43:27:
    No instance for (Num [Double]) arising from a use of `rk4'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Double])
    In the first argument of `iterate', namely `(rk4 fs h)'
    In the expression: iterate (rk4 fs h) initial
    In an equation for `result': result = iterate (rk4 fs h) initial
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Where Haskell has inferred the type of rk4 to be

```
rk4  :: (Fractional b, Num [b]) => [[b] -> [b] -> b] -> b -> [[b]] -> [[b]]
```

The source code

```
module Pendulum where
import Data.List

{-
  The simple pendulum

  This is system which obeys the following equation.

  $ \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} + \frac{g}{L}\theta = 0 $

  where g is the acceleration due to gravity, L the length of the pendulum and theta
  the angular displacement of the pendulum

  By observation you could see thar for small angles the solution for simple harmonic osscilator could be used,
  but for large angles a numerical solution is required.

  This simulation uses the Runge Kutta 4th Order Method to solve the ODE.

-}

data PhysicalParam = PhysicalParam { pMass   :: Double -- kg   Pendulum mass
                                   , pLength :: Double -- m    Pendulum length
                                   }
data PendulumState = PendulumState { omega   :: Double -- rad/s Angular Velocity
                                   , theta   :: Double -- rad   Angular Displacement
                                   , time    :: Double -- s     Time
                                   }
type Time = Double
type TIncrement = Double

list2State :: [[Double]] -> PendulumState
list2State [xs, ys]  = PendulumState { theta = (ys !! 0)
                                     , omega = (ys !! 1)
                                     , time  = (xs !! 0)
                                     }

state2List :: PendulumState -> [[Double]]
state2List state = [[time state],[theta state, omega state ]]


--pendulum :: PhysicalParam -> PendulumState -> Time -> TIncrement -> [PendulumState]
pendulum physicalParam initState time dt = result -- map list2State result
  where result = iterate (rk4 fs h) initial
        omegaDerivative pp state = adg * sin (theta state) / (pLength pp)
        thetaDerivative pp state = omega state
        fs   = [(\xs ys -> omegaDerivative physicalParam (list2State [xs, ys]))
               ,(\xs ys -> thetaDerivative physicalParam (list2State [xs, ys]))
               ]
        initial  = state2List initState
        h   = dt
        adg = 9.81 -- m/s

--rk4 :: Floating a => [ [a] -> [a] -> a ] -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
rk4 fs h [xs, ys] = [xs', ys']
  where xs' = map (+h) xs
        ys' = ys + map (*(h/6.0)) (k1 + (map (*2.0) k2) + (map (*2.0) k3) + k4)
          where k1 = [f (xs)              (ys)                     | f <- fs]
                k2 = [f (map (+0.5*h) xs) (ys + map (*(0.5*h)) k1) | f <- fs]
                k3 = [f (map (+0.5*h) xs) (ys + map (*(0.5*h)) k2) | f <- fs]
                k4 = [f (map (+1.0*h) xs) (ys + map (*(1.0*h)) k3) | f <- fs]

physParam = PhysicalParam { pMass = 1.0, pLength = 0.1 }

-- Initial Conditions
initState = PendulumState { omega = 1.0, theta   = 1.0, time = 0.0 }

dt = 1.0/100   -- time increment
simTime = 30.0 -- simulation time

simulatedStates = pendulum physParam initState simTime dt
```

Comment: If you're having type errors and you don't quite get them, I've found it helps to lift the values you define in the where-clauses of functions to the top level (adding parameters as needed) and then use GHCi to get the inferred types for those and add those inferred types to the source code. That way you have more type information and can more easily figure out the mismatch between what you want and what you coded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When something like `Num [b]` turns up in an inferred type, you can be quite sure there appears a numerical literal where GHC expects a list, or a list turns up as one of the arguments to a numerical operator. And indeed:

```
... ys + map (*(0.5*h)) k1 ...
```

both `ys` and `k1` are lists, but `+` is numerical addition.

Perhaps you're trying to use `++` here, but let me tell you your whole approach is less than nice. Why do you accept `[xs, ys]` as a always–two-element list? Start with a reasonable signature, something similar to

```
rk4 :: (Floating a, Floating t) => [a -> t -> a] -> a -> [t] -> [a]`
```

Write that down first of all, and then start to implement the function *from the outside to the inside*, first leaving more local subexpressions `undefined`. Compile in frequent intervals, and when an error turns up you'll immediately see where.

---

**BTW.** It's not really great to use Haskell lists for implementing mathematical vectors, on any level. The "right" version of Runge-Kutta, IMO, has a signature along the lines

```
rk4 :: (VectorSpace v, t ~ Scalar v, Floating t)
     => (v -> t -> v) -> v -> [t] -> [v]
```

with [a proper type-safe vector class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.8.6/doc/html/Data-VectorSpace.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and advice. For some reason I expected “(+) x y” to do “addList x y = zipWith (+) x y”. I have muddled up the program as I copied a JavaScript program I had written previously and tried to convert it into Haskell bit by bit. The xs and ys were used to represent the time and the state variables of the system respectively at each time increment, but I admit that the use of lists of floats was a bad idea. I will try to write better type signatures and to use hole driven development till I get the hang of Haskell.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `t ~ Scalar v`, rather than using `Floating (Scalar v)`, `((v, Scalar v) -> v)`, and so on?  Just curious if it helps instance inference/cuts down on extensions/something or if it's just a style choice.

Comment: @AntalS-Z just style choice. I don't like having to repeat `Scalar` twice. Also, it's somewhat useful to have a type variable here, as it hints at what the _meaning_ of `t` is. You also wouldn't use point-free style all the time on the value-level, would you?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Thanks!  I hadn't seen the style before, so I was just wondering.  I do like the idea, I'll have to keep it in mind.